# Add a product to multiple categories

Tags: e-commerce, tree, categorization, multiple-products

I would like a user to be able to add a same product to multiple categories and sub-categories.

The purpose of this so the Navigation Menu Bar (categories) on the e-commerce website could be generated dynamically of categories and sub-categories.

In term of UX, I think it could increase findability of the products?

I am thinking using jsTree plugin on the backend to represent categories and subcategories. Could also allow products to be moved in bulk to different nodes of the tree. If this is bad UX what is alternative better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will increase the find-ability of the product. We did it with "Pen-drive". Pen-drive falls into multiple categories, it can be described as Hardware or an Electronic. While user research, we found that certain user associated it with Hardware and other with Electronics. So we added it under both the categories. The result is both can find the product through their own understanding of the product.

Comment: How did you apply a product to multiple categories? Using Tree Node?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using tag for that purpose.
It's an easy way that a product belongs to several categories
I leave two links that refer to topic

[Do non-technical/non-web savvy users understand the concept of tags?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/do-non-technical-non-web-savvy-users-understand-the-concept-of-tags)

[What is the expected paging behavior of a tree?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/what-is-the-expected-paging-behavior-of-a-tree)

Greetings.